# Activerecord - Executing complex queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to execute the following query in "Activerecord". How can I do that? Please help me..

```
query = "SELECT rc.constraint_schema||'.'||tc.table_name AS table_name, kcu.column_name FROM information_schema.referential_constraints AS rc JOIN information_schema.table_constraints AS tc USING(constraint_catalog,constraint_schema,constraint_name) JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu USING(constraint_catalog,constraint_schema,constraint_name) JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS ccu ON(ccu.constraint_catalog=rc.unique_constraint_catalog AND ccu.constraint_schema=rc.unique_constraint_schema AND ccu.constraint_name=rc.unique_constraint_name) WHERE ccu.table_catalog=\"#{connection_parameters['database']}\" AND ccu.table_schema=\"#{connection_parameters['schema_search_path']}\" AND ccu.table_name=\"#{tab}\" AND ccu.column_name=\"#{select}\""
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `select_rows` from inside a model method:

```
def some_method
    query = "... big pile of SQL ..."
    connection.select_rows(sql).each do |row|
        table_name, column_name = *row
        #...
    end
end
```